# Electrum is not listing "unconfirmed transcation" in History tab after 4 days. Can I send new transactions?

Tags: bitcoin-core, unconfirmed-transactions, electrum

I am using Electrum(2.6.4) and has an unconfirmed transaction from last 4 days. I tried viaBtc accelerator as well in these days. Yesterday, I stopped my Electrum wallet in my PC and restarted after several hours. It connected to the network and hurray... I don't see the unconfirmed transaction listed. I thought it was removed from memory pool and bitcoins deposited back to my wallet. But today morning when I started Electrum wallet it shows the unconfirmed transaction again :(

So, I believe I can't depend on Electrum to confirm if the transaction is removed from the memory pool. Hence, can someone please confirm how can we check if the transaction has been forgotten from blockchain memory pools?

Transaction ID - https://tradeblock.com/bitcoin/tx/1bd51d7aad1635001799918144c9dedeb6e71b56bef65c4e975cd8a5eb306632

Thanks!

Comment: Hope someone helps:(

Answer (score 0):

You can try an online Bitcoin blockchain explorer, such as:

- https://blockchain.info/unconfirmed-transactions
- https://tradeblock.com/bitcoin/explorer/

search your transaction and see if you can find it there!

Comment: I checked these blockchain explorers and I see 1st one shows it https://blockchain.info/tx/1bd51d7aad1635001799918144c9dedeb6e71b56bef65c4e975cd8a5eb306632 and the second one says "This transaction is unknown" https://btc.blockr.io/tx/info/1bd51d7aad1635001799918144c9dedeb6e71b56bef65c4e975cd8a5eb306632.

Comment: And my Electrum wallet doesn't list this transaction after restarting it after some hours..

Comment: your tx is still unconfirmed and in the mempool. You chose a very low tx fee, so that's why.

Comment: As my Electrum is not listing this unconfirmed transaction now, is it safe to send new transactions with higher fees? Will it end up making things more complicated?

Comment: the wallet records may not be up-to-date for various reasons, popular online explorers are almost always reliable. here's your tx on tradeblock : https://tradeblock.com/bitcoin/tx/1bd51d7aad1635001799918144c9dedeb6e71b56bef65c4e975cd8a5eb306632

Comment: sure, send with higher transaction fee and it will get to the next block way sooner. so you're set to go. choose a reasonable  tx fee from here : https://bitcoinfees.21.co/

Comment: Are you sure?? Sorry, am really afraid of these bitcoins transactions and am a newbee to this. So, as this particular trnasaction is still shown in explorers, is it safe to send new ones from Electrum?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58929/discussion-between-mostafa-bahri-and-rob).

Answer (score 0):

Bitcoin transactions never expire. Because of this, anyone on the network can store your transaction and rebroadcast it any time they like.

Bitcoin Core will remove unconfirmed transactions that have been around for more than 48 hours, but anyone on the network can re-add it.

To answer your second question, you can send another transaction.